# Запуск и работа функции во всех контроллерах в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте!
Хочу с помощью accept-language определять язык пользователя, и записывать в соответствии с этими данными в сессию несколько значений.

Собственно, из-за этого есть 2 вопроса:

1. Каким образом можно исполнять код вне зависимости от того, к какому контроллеру обратился пользователей? Ибо копипастить код в каждый контроллер совсем не выход.
2. Каким образом её провернуть до начала работы контроллера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наследовать контроллеры от одного и исспользовать `beforeActions()`

Переопределить компонент `Request` или какой то другой.

Написать свой компонент и положить его в `boostrap`

Comment: Хм, а можно поподробнее о компоненте? Нужно будет ли его вызывать в контроллере каждый раз?

Comment: Подозреваю чт вы про 3-й вариант, тут подробнее - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#bootstrap